# Diode preventing coil from latching?

Tags: diodes, coil, flyback

So I've come across a case where an input from a little 5v I/O system will trigger the coil of a reed switch but not it's direct equivalent that has a built in flyback diode and changing the resistors that are in series with the input doesn't seem to work. Far as I can tell it's a CV supply though. Thoughts on getting it to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the obvious suggestion is to make sure that the polarity is correct.

With the diode in there you have to pay attention to the polarity, otherwise bad things will happen. If you're substituting for an equivalent part 'socket' without a diode, you have a 50/50 chance of it working.

Comment: That's kind of what I figured. According to both datasheets the pin configuration is the same with the input going to the correct side. I suppose it's possible that whoever built the little thing I'm working on used DC- for the input, an odd choice though. Thanks, I'll switch the connections around and hope it works.